# "on the other hand" or "on the contrary"

Tags: phrase-usage

I'd like to know which phrase to use in the following:

> John is bad at playing baseball. On the other hand/On the contrary, he plays basketball very well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> On the other hand, he plays basketball very well.

This is the correct answer, stating that while {one thing} is {one way}, another thing is the opposite.  "On the contrary" is for a statement that **contradicts** a previous statement and **reinforces** a rejection of that statement.  For example:

> People say that John is bad at playing baseball, but this isn't true.  On the contrary, he has won many championships.

Here, the statement being contradicted is "Jon is bad at baseball", and the rejection being reinforced is "but this isn't true".  Both these elements should be in place before using "on the contrary".

Comment: Maybe the OP was thinking of "in contrast".

Comment: >> '... another thing is the opposite'.  Perhaps: 'another thing is *different*'.  Baseball ineptitude isn't really the opposite of basketball talent.  Hands are alternate, not opposite.

Comment: It's more along the lines of "ineptitude" is opposite of "talent".  It's just that these opposites apply to different things, as I said.  You wouldn't use "On the other hand" for non-contrasting things.  We wouldn't say "John is bad at baseball, on the other hand, he sucks at basketball" because "bad" and "sucks" aren't opposites.